# How I can get the rowcount of a tableLayoutPanel from another form?

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I have a form1 and a button. This button created a new form with a TableLayoutPanel (already filled for the test).

Is it possible to get the `RowCount` and display it in the button text in the first form (form1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the TableLayoutPanel on the second form is initialized onload, then you can create a property/method that returns the count. On form1 when you load form2 on button click, the code might look something like this.

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
int count = frm2.GetTableRowCount()
btn.Text  = count.ToString();
```

Where GetTableRowCount() method on form 2 returns the table row count.